# Meaning of "did" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The committee members took turns talking about why we were there. And then I got up and **did** my piece.

Then in there, "did" refer to "took turns talking about"?

And that means "I said my opinion"?

++
This quote is from Harry Potter, and the next sentence is

> said how Buckbeak was a good hippogriff.

I've missed 'said' in the next script ㅠㅠ!

Comment: Yes, you got it. You did your part of standing up and talking about why you all were present in the first place.

Comment: No - grammatically speaking ***did*** simply refers to ***my piece***. It's *possible* "my piece" is another example of someone talking about why they are present at the meeting, but it's equally possible that what the speaker does (after all those "Why are we here?" speeches) is something completely different. Which may or may not have some kind of connection to whatever came before - that's just a matter of specific context that we don't know.

Comment: (Note that ***I did my piece*** here is both vague and slangy. It's not really possible to say what exactly it "means" here without a ***lot*** more context - ideally, actually *watching* what the speaker does next.)

Comment: ...for example, perhaps all the committee members are attending the meeting because they've been fiddling the accounts and stealing money, and they're meeting to decide what to do, since they now realise the company is going bankrupt. But we've no idea whether the *speaker* here is also about to admit to having done the same as them - for all we know, he's an undercover detective who intends to blackmail them, because he knows what's been going on. Or he's going to read them their rights and arrest them. Who knows?

Comment: Where is this quote from?  It would be more natural to say, "And then I got up and **said** my piece."

Comment: Hagrid says this in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban. What's there to say for it? This is just how Hagrid speaks. Certainly Hagrid doesn't speak perfect, Oxford standard English. In fact, the most believable people seldom do.

Comment: Here I think "did my piece" means "made my speech".

Comment: I think it’s just bad writing. Normally it would be “said my piece” or “did my part”. Rowling tells a good story, but I find a lot of her writing very clumsy.